# Cross product shortcuts

Tags: vectors, absolute-value, cross-product

Given two vectors $a=(1,t, t^{3})$ $b=(0,1,3t^{2})$

I have seen that $|a\times b|^{2} = (1+t^{2}+t^{6})(1+9t^{4})-(t+3t^{5})^{2}$

It seems that its has been done in some shorthand way maybe other than calculating the cross product then the absolute value then squaring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the identity $(a\times b)\cdot (a\times b)=(a\cdot a)(b\cdot b)-(a\cdot b)^2$, which is essentially the cartesian coordinates version of $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$.

Comment: @url Your edit was unnecessary, because $(a\times b)\cdot(a\times b)$ is always a non negative real number. If anything, the only thing that changes is what happens if $\cdot$ is the Hermitian product $\langle;\rangle$ in $\Bbb C^3$. In that case the identity of interest is $$\langle a\times b; a\times b\rangle=\langle a;a\rangle\langle b; b\rangle-\lvert\langle a; b\rangle\rvert^2=\langle a;a\rangle\langle b; b\rangle-\langle a; b\rangle\langle b; a\rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

Look at $|a\cdot b|^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2 \cos^2(\theta_{a,b}) = |a|^2|b|^2-|a\times b|^2$
so $|a\times b|^2 = a^2 b^2 - (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})^2$

I like this method since it doesn't require knowledge of the cross-product identities or levi-civita symbol depending on your flavor preference.